# Running a .jar with code

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to run a jar file from code - in a "launcher". The launcher is an applet, which downloads the needed files.

But for some reason, it only works on some computers? I can't seem to make any link between the computers it doesn't work on. Below is my code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(System.getProperty("java.home") + "\\bin\\javaw", "-jar", data_jarToRun, data_authKey);
    pb.directory(new File(directory));
    try {
        pb.start();
        window.setStage("Launched!");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        window.setFailed();
        window.setData("Failed to launch!");
    }
```

Note that:

- data_jarToRun equals "theJar.jar"
- data_authKey is a String that needs to be included in "theJar" arguments.
- directory is the folder that "theJar" is found in.

Comment: On the machines that are failing does specifically calling "java -jar theJar.jar" from the command line work?

Comment: Haven't tested that, can't access any of the failing computers currently since they're not mine. :(

Comment: Where is the jar you ate trying to run coming from? Is the applet signed? On the machines where it fails, can you have the user open the java console so you can see the exact exception getting thrown? What OS and JVM versions is it failing on?

Comment: Are you doing anything to get around the security restrictions that prevent applets from accessing local files or running native code? Explain in detail how the applet is being launched.

Comment: This won't work on non-Windows machines... is that it?

Comment: You should be seeing a security error at `System.exit(0)` - not even ***trusted*** applets are allowed to do that!